# How do I select an item from dropdown in selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I'm trying to select 'Newest' from the drop-down menu.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en&showAllReviews=true'
driver.get(url)

state_selection = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='%s']" % "Most relevant")
state_selection.click()
state_selection.send_keys(Keys.UP)
state_selection.send_keys(Keys.UP)
state_selection2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='%s']" % "Newest")
state_selection2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

but as soon as it reaches Newest and as I send command to press enter(as shown in code),it resets to "Most Relevent". I'm not able to get my head around on how to achieve this.

Comment: Remove the second search for `state_selection2` and do `state_selection.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`. You've already hit up twice

Comment: @MadPhysicist if I do so it returns an exception "element not visible"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have clicked state_selection, something like this will click "Newest":

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='option']/span[contains(text(),'Newest')]").click()
```

The more robust method would be working with `WebdriverWait` to allow the DOM to update, so:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='option']/span[contains(text(),'Newest')]"))).click()
```

Note you need these imports for `WebdriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to find

- Index
- Value
- Visible Text

When you use the xpath if the values are changed in future,it pick that element present in that location only.So its better to user select by visible text

```
state_selection=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='%s']" % "Most relevant").click();
state_selection.select_by_visible_text("Dropdown Visible Text")
```